# Most effective way to write File to ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, performance, file, servlets, nio

```
ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
output.write(byte[]);
```

What is the most effective way to write File to javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream?

**EDIT:**

won't this be more effective if the NIO was used?

Comment: nio is not a magic bullet which makes everything io based faster.  in fact, nio is generally helpful if you need to make your code more _scalable_ (e.g. fewer threads handling more connections).  for single threaded code, io is almost always as good or better (exception to this rule may be file to file transfer).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
out.flush();
//...........
out.close(); // depends on your application
```

Where `in` is the [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and `out` is the `SocketOutputStream`.
[IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) is a utility from [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) module in [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/).

Comment: +1, but two notes - it's "apache commons", and you can use `IOUtils.closeQuitely(..)`

Comment: @Bozho it used to be called Jakarta Commons many years ago :-)

Comment: that doesn't work for me, I don't want to add Commons IO jar just for that functionality.

Comment: won't this be more effective if the NIO was used?

Comment: @01 adding a dependency on apache commons rarely has any downsides ;)

Comment: Bozho it has a very huge downside, i will have to fight with my boss, because of it. i rather reinvent the wheel than fight with him.

Answer (score 6):

You have a ServletOutputStream. The only way you can write to that is via java.io.*. You can't use NIO on it at all (other than via wrapping with `Channels`, which is pointless: it's still an `OutputStream` underneath and you are just adding processing over the top). The actual I/O is network-bound, and your writes are being buffered anyway by the servlet container (so that it can set the Content-Length) header so looking for performance tweaks here is pointless.

Comment: @01: Yes, you can use NIO's channels if you use Channels.newChannel(OutputStream). Which wraps the output stream in a channel. It is still talking to an underlying ByteArrayOutputStream. There is no efficiency gain in this situation. It is pointless.

Comment: @JerylCook I addessed that in comments **five and a half years ago** and have so far attracted 5 comment votes for having done so. Look.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is unrelated to servlets. This applies to Java IO in general. You have after all just an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream`.

As to the answer, you're not the only one who wondered about this. On the interwebs you can find others who wondered about the same but took the effort to test/benchmark it themselves:

- [Java tip: How to read files quickly?](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly)
- [File copy in Java - Benchmark](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/08/file-copy-in-java-benchmark/)

In general, a [`FileChannel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) with a 256K byte array which is read through a wrapped [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and written directly from the byte array is the fastest way. Indeed, NIO.

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file.ext");
FileChannel channel = input.getChannel();
byte[] buffer = new byte[256 * 1024];
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);

try {
    for (int length = 0; (length = channel.read(byteBuffer)) != -1;) {
        System.out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        byteBuffer.clear();
    }
} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: The first link actually seems to recommend an 8K buffer since the time to copy difference between 8 and 256K is minimal. That seems to make sense given that most file systems still use 4KB pages and 4KB disk clusters.

Comment: Difference is indeed minimal. OP is however asking for "effective way" not "efficient way". 8K is still fast but less memory consuming in case of a busy site.

Comment: What about using channels and Channel.transferTo ?

Comment: @IAdapter In general, using `transferTo()` will give the best performance; unfortunately, the Servlet API doesn't expose the `SocketChannel`, so the optimization isn't available.

Comment: where do you write it to an ServletOutputStream?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you are using Java 9 or above you could use the `InputStream.transferTo` method straightaway:

```
inputStream.transferTo(outputStream);
```

Which seems clean and handy. The method is not available in Java 8 (1.8) though.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to add that jar to your application then you have to copy it by hand. Just copy the method implementation from here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/io/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java?revision=1004358&view=markup:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

public static int copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
  long count = copyLarge(input, output);
  if (count > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    return -1;
  }
  return (int) count;
}

public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
    throws IOException {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
   long count = 0;
   int n = 0;
   while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
     output.write(buffer, 0, n);
     count += n;
   }
   return count;
}
```

put those 2 methods in one of your helper classes and you're good to go.

Comment: won't this be more effective if the NIO was used?

Comment: i had mixed results with nio :). It might be better or it might not. The code is definitely a little more complex and you really need to test the results on your machine to make sure is good enough. Look here for some code: http://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/fast-stream-copy-using-javanio-channels/

Comment: +1 ymmv, but i've had a hard time making the nio version faster than good old streams