# IOUtils.copy and IOUtils.copyLarge are very slow

Tags: java, http, inputstream, apache-commons-io

I've implemented a REST service for downloading a moderately large (250 Mb) zip file using IOUtils.copy(), similar to [Most effective way to write file to servletoutputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645441/most-effective-way-to-write-file-to-servletoutputstream). The REST service is called from another app using HttpURLConnection. I use IOUtils.copy() on the receiving side to save the file to disk.

It takes over 30 minutes to download a file. This is **way** too slow.

Ideas? Better implementations?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for us to inspect?

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested by `BalusC` on the same page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4647337/20634 ? If yes, what are the results ?

Comment: Its highly unlikely to be due to software. Its far more likely to be due to bandwidth or hardware issues. The transfer rate is 1.1 Mb/s which is a common limit for broadband upload speeds.

Comment: I haven't implemented FileChannels from BalusC, since I've seen no indication that they go faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue.

I was running both the client and the server on the same machine for testing. As soon as I moved one to a different machine, the transfer took a little over a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the source code and see for yourself that the default buffer size is 4096. 
I personally used 8192 as buffer size in a specific case. 
Consider playing with the buffer size. 
You can implement this copy quite easily on your own, or see the source file [here](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copyLarge%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29), as a reference. 
In addition, consider performing multi-threaded download, if possible as your server supports multiple connections (I assume).

Comment: The link to the source file is broken!