# Java - Make byte array as a download

Tags: java, java-6

I have a zip file as a byte array (byte[]), I could write it to the file system using,

```
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\test1.zip");
        fos.write(decodedBytes);  // decodedBytes is the zip file as a byte array 
        fos.close();
```

Instead of writing it to a file and reading it to make it as a download, I would like to make the byte array as a download directly, 
I tried this,

```
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"File.zip\"");
    ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(decodedBytes);  // decodedBytes is the zip file as a byte array
```

This is not working, I'm getting empty file. How can I make the byte array as a download?

**Update:**
I added finally clause and closed the ServletOutputStream and it worked.

```
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.error(this, e);
    } finally {
        try{
            if (outStream != null) {
                outStream.close();              
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.error(this, "Download: Error during closing resources");
        }
    }
```

Pankaj solution also works.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989215/how-to-convert-a-byte-into-a-file-with-a-download-dialog-box

Comment: Did you make sure that `decodedBytes` actually has data in it? Have you tried _not_ zipping the data first?

Comment: @MattBall I checked the length of byte[] in eclipse debug, it matches the physical zip file. Actually the byte[] comes from DB, which was already zipped and stored in a BLOB.

Comment: outStream.flush() put after outstream.write()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try following:

```
ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="DATA.ZIP"");
outStream.write(decodedBytes);
outStream.flush();
```